# I always exaggerate everything I say by 25%. By how much do I truly exaggerate?

Tags: fractions, percentages

'I always exaggerate everything I say by 25%. By how much do I truly exaggerate?'

Hi, I asked myself this question and it is starting to give me a headache. Does anyone have a correct solution? Thanks

Comment: Do we have to consider that you also exaggerate not all the time, but 75% of the time by x amount?

Comment: Nice, hadn't thought of this. If 'always' is treated as 100% then yes.

Comment: In fact 'everything' could also be treated as a percentage. Rephrased this would be: '100% of the time I exaggerate 100% of what I say by 25%. By how much do I truly exaggerate?'

Answer (score 4):

$20.7\%$ approximately.

If you exaggerate by $x\%$ then you are multiplying by $1 + \frac{x}{100}$.

We know that $x \times (1 + \frac{x}{100}) = 25$.

Solving for $x$ using the quadartic formula leads to the correct result.

Nice question. :)

Answer (score 1):

Let $x$ be the fraction you exaggerate everything by.

Then $25\%$ is equal to $x$ exaggerated by $x$, so $x(1+x) = 25\%$.

Solving this quadratic equation yields $x = \frac{\pm\sqrt{2} - 1}{2}$.

So either you exaggerate everything by $20.71067811865\%$, or you exaggerate everything by $-120.71067811865\%$.